# Get the current DateTime - Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to create a custom Lightning Component that has the same behavior as the new event with StartDateTime and EndDateTime fields. But my problem is that i cannot set the current date time in my attribute on the javascript doInit function. I suspect it's because the format of the date in Lightning is different. How could i set now datetime my input? Code below:
CMP

```
<!-- 2020-05-12 @ggalaios This Lightning Component handles the Start Date and End Date as well as Is All Day Event on event record-->

<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <!-- Define Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="inputType" type="String" default="datetime"/> <!-- set dynamically the type of the input -->
    <aura:attribute name="startDatetime" type="Datetime" />
    <!-- Handlers Declaration -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <lightning:input type="{!v.inputType}" name="startDateTime" value="{!v.startDatetime}" label="{!$Label.c.Start}" onchange="{!c.handleHourChange}" />
    <lightning:input type="{!v.inputType}" name="endDateTime" label="{!$Label.c.End}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller JS

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
        var time = (today.getHours() +1) + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        var dateTime = date+' '+time;
        console.log('Date Time is: ' +dateTime);
        //component.set("v.startDatetime", dateTime);
    },

    handleHourChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('handled');
        console.log(component.get("v.startDatetime"));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a proper ISO-time format:

```
<aura:attribute name="startDatetime" type="string" />
```

...

```
component.set("v.startDatetime", today.toISOString());
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for one more time!!! hahah... Do you maybe know if / how it would be possible to set the current datetime but for the hour section to put the nearest next hour?

Comment: @GiorgosGalaios `today.getMinutes() && today.setMinutes(60); component.set("v.startDatetime", today);` would do this. By setting the value to 60 minutes, the Date object automatically adds up to an hour, rolling over to the next day if necessary.

Comment: You saved my day, sfdcfox. Thank you so much!!!